# Alignment in linear layout - Android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout

Provided a Vertical linear layout, I would wish to align the text centre vertically.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sample1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sample2"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"/>
```

I would wish to have "sample1" at centre vertically, NOTE: layout_gravity="center" just provides alignment by horizontal centre and not vertical centred.

Refer [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4BU2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS .

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="sample1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="sample2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to go with relative layout. Try this way it will work for you

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/sample1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="sample1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sample1"
        android:text="sample2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]